# Return items from array sequentially on each function call, false when no more exist

Tags: php

I need to have a function that sort of acts like mysql resources sometimes do, where you have to "fetch" something as part of a loop until it returns false.

I have something like:

```
while ($variable = $object->method())
{
  // Do stuff with variable here
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how, on my object, to best keep track of what to send from the method.

```
class object {
  $values = array(1, 2);
  public function method()
    {
      // First call should return 1, second should return 2, and any subsequent calls should return FALSE
      // Not sure now what to do
      // return $values[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `return array_shift($values)` in your case. ([docs](http://php.net/array_shift)).

Comment: Please note that this returns `NULL` and not `FALSE` if there are no more items in array

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`each()`](http://php.net/each) function. It moves the array's internal pointer and returns the current value. If no more values are present, it returns false.

```
return each($values);
```

it also has the advantage of not being destructive.

Comment: `each()` is the correct solution. Mine (using `array_shift()`) destroys the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your object "traversable" via foreach either by implementing the [Iterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or the [IteratorAggregate](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) interface, e.g.:

```
<?php
class object implements IteratorAggregate {
  protected $values;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->values = range(1,10);
  }
  public function getIterator() {
    return new ArrayIterator($this->values);
  }
}

$o = new object;
foreach( $o as $e ) {
    echo $e;
}
```

prints `12345678910`